# Execute JS only after the entire page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to optimize a piece of JS (it's a company details - address, phone number etc. verification badge). I really don't need it, but it pulls info from two different CDN's, which adds up to my page speed.

The line looks like this:

`<script src="https://d20iczrsxk7wft.cloudfront.net/botwverified/badge.js?id=1234567"></script>`

It is possible (jquery is already loaded for other stuff) to make this appear, or load, only after the page completely loaded? Probably JS? I know nothing about JS. My page loads in 1.5 second and this badge takes an extra second load.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery to load the script dynamically.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("https://d20iczrsxk7wft.cloudfront.net/botwverified/badge.js?id=1234567");
});
</script>
```

The `ready()` function calls the function after the page is loaded.

Comment: Hi Barmar, could you please paste me the exact code I have to paste in my html page? Thanks!

Comment: That's the exact code. It just goes into your `<script>` block, like the rest of your jQuery code.

Comment: Well, now it's not showing at all. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Yep. Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):555

Comment: That shouldn't happen if jQuery is already loaded. Make sure this script is after jquery.

Comment: It is loaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript, window.onload will do the job.